# select an element between 2 element and replace

Tags: jquery, replace

Hello I want to replace the word 'Register' to 'Hello' right after  node

The problem is the word 'Register' is not inside any separate element thats why I can't select with any selector and edit it. and I can't wrap it with any selector either cause the html is generated dynamically by php , and I can't edit php codes thats why I need jquery help.

```
  <div id="register_portion">
      <h3>Not registered? No problem!</h3>
      Register <!-- I want to change this text -->
      <div class="tml tml-register" id="theme-my-login1">
          <p class="message">Please register now.</p>
          <form name="registerform" id="registerform1" 
               action="/login-now/?pending=activation&amp;instance=1" 
                method="post">
                      form html...
          </form>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Show your effort?

Comment: Put it in div, and manipulate with JS...

Comment: Why don't you just wrap this text into e.x. `<span class='replace'>` and then use jQuery `.html()` function?

Comment: What do you mean select an element between 2 element? Selectors for that purpose are pretty simple in jQuery. Did you read how to do it before asking?

Comment: The question is not clear. You have the word register 2 times in your div. Not sure  what you really try to accomplish. 
Please read: http://api.jquery.com/text/
And: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp
And: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

Comment: @Satpal I have tried several ways not any possible way found , so showing my effort will not help.

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek the text register is generating dynamically from a wordpress plugin , so I can't add wrap with span , if I can wrap with span I can change that text from there also . jquery help will not be needed

Comment: @JonesJoseph the problem is the word 'Register' is not in any identical selector , thats why I can't easily change the text with .html() or text(), thats why I need to select the node/text between 2 selectors and edit it.

Comment: use `next()` or `prev()`

Comment: @CarlosMartins the word register in my div is 2 times but I want to replace only first one. the first one is not inside any separate selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the following sibling of `h3` element, Use [`get()`](https://api.jquery.com/get/) to get the underlying DOM element then using [`nextSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nextSibling) property target the node, then you can use [`nodeValue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeValue) to set its text.

```js
$("#register_portion h3").get(0).nextSibling.nodeValue = "Hello";
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="register_portion">
  <h3>Not registered? No problem!</h3>
  Register
  <!-- I want to change this text -->
  <div class="tml tml-register" id="theme-my-login1">
    <p class="message">Please register now.</p>
    <form name="registerform" id="registerform1" action="/login-now/?pending=activation&amp;instance=1" method="post">
      form html...
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

Declare a span with class `.replaceText`

```
<span class="replaceText">Register</span>
```

Use `.text` function to set the value of span element

```
$('.replaceText').text('Hello');
```

Here is [solution](https://jsfiddle.net/fnmbxkcv/1/)

Comment: I can't declare a span , the html is generating dynamically by php , I can't edit the php codes. thats why I need jquery help

Answer (score 0):

Enclose it inside a `div` or a `span`. Access that element using `id` or `class` or the element itself. Then use:

```
 $('YourElement').html('YourText');
```

OR

```
$('YourElement').text('YourText');
```

Code below satisfies your condition:

```js
$('#hello').html('Hello')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="register_portion"><h3>Not registered? No problem!</h3>
    <div id="hello">Register</div> <!-- I want to change this text -->
    <div class="tml tml-register" id="theme-my-login1">
    <p class="message">Please register now.</p>
    <form name="registerform" id="registerform1" action="/login-now/?pending=activation&amp;instance=1" method="post">form html...</form>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I can't enclose with a div , the html is generating dynamically by php , I can't edit the php codes. thats why I need jquery help

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#register_portion').contents().filter(function() {
  return this.nodeType == 3;
}).replaceWith("qweqwew");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="register_portion">
  <h3>Not registered? No problem!</h3>
  Register
  <!-- I want to change this text -->
  <div class="tml tml-register" id="theme-my-login1">
    <p class="message">Please register now.</p>
    <form name="registerform" id="registerform1" action="/login-now/?pending=activation&amp;instance=1" method="post">form html...</form>
  </div>
```

If only one text node is available inside `register_portion` you can do this